# Ошибка при генерации объектов для базы данных в Dart

Tags: база-данных, dart

Есть три класса, и для них есть, также, три `Bean` класса.
Запускаю генерацию, но получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Exception while parsing field: variables!
Exception while parsing field: trackedVariable!
Exception: Non-bean type provided!
```

Ошибка в виде `StackTrace` в созданном файле.
Зависимости подтянул:

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
     sdk: flutter
   sqflite:
   jaguar_orm: ^2.2.0
   jaguar_query_sqflite: ^2.2.0

dev_dependencies:
   flutter_test:
     sdk: flutter
   jaguar_orm_gen: ^2.2.0
   build_runner: ^0.10.0
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В классах `...Bean`, которые нужно создать для генерации дополнительных классов не нужно наследовать и реализовывать методы, хотя и обозначает красным подчеркиванием.